# How to run `docker exec -it <container_name> bash -c "some commands"` using golang sdk

Tags: bash, docker, go

I'm using docker's sdk in golang to execute a `docker exec` command.

```
func (dn *dockerNode) execCommand(ctx context.Context, cmd []string) (*execResult, error) {
    execId, err := dn.cl.ContainerExecCreate(ctx, dn.contId, types.ExecConfig{
        AttachStderr: true,
        AttachStdout: true,
        Tty:          true,
        Cmd:          cmd,
    })

    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf(
            "cannot create command \"%s\":\n %v",
            strings.Join(cmd, " "),
            err,
        )
    }

    res, err := dn.InspectExecResp(ctx, execId.ID)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf(
            "cannot execute command \"%s\":\n %v",
            strings.Join(cmd[:], " "),
            err,
        )
    }

    if res.exitCode != 0 {
        return &res, fmt.Errorf(
            "command \"%s\" exit with code %d:\n %+v",
            strings.Join(cmd[:], " "),
            res.exitCode,
            res)
    }

    return &res, nil
}
```

This `dn.execCommand` works fine just for some vanilla `docker exec foo bar` format command, but now I'd like to use it to run something equivalent to `docker exec bash -c "cd mydir && ./my_shell.sh"`. This is because the `cd` command only works with `docker exec bash -c`. I tried passing this with

```
    res, err = dn.execCommand(
        ctx,
        []string{
            "bash",
            "-c",
            "\"cd mydir && ./my_shell.sh\"",
        },
    )
```

But it gave me `command "bash -c "cd mydir && ./my_shell.sh" " exit with code 127`

I wonder how to modify the original function to make it support the `docker exec bash -c`  use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last command has an extra layer of quotes.

```golang
command := []string{
        "bash",
        "-c",
        "cd mydir && ./my_shell.sh",
//      ^^no quotes inside string^^
}
```

If you were to run a similar command on the host

```sh
bash -c "cd mydir && ./my_shell.sh"
```

the shell would take the double-quoted string and turn it into a single word, and then discard the quotes.  You can see this in part by putting the word `echo` in front of the command line, so the processed command gets printed out rather than executed; the double-quotes will be gone.  What you're running is more similar to

```sh
bash -c '"cd mydir && ./my_shell.sh"'
```

Also note that the [`"github.com/docker/docker/api/types".ExecConfig`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker@v20.10.12+incompatible/api/types#ExecConfig) structure contains a `WorkingDir` field, so you might be able to avoid this wrapper.  Scripting `docker exec` also frequently isn't the best design, since you need unlimited administrator-level permissions over the host to use it, and since a container typically only runs one process.

Comment: Thanks! the `WorkingDir` field works perfectly for me!!